# How to get each label and respective li in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having below dynamic generated html div.In that i need to get each label and its respective `li` items.using that label value i need to call a function.But cant able get each value i am getting same value repeatedly.Someone help me to solve.

Html:

```
<div class="row extra-attri-div">
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="environment">environment</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-environment">
               <li>Suburban</li>
               <li>Urban</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="income_coarse">income_coarse</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-income_coarse">
               <li>Middle Class</li>
               <li>Upper Middle Class</li>
               <li>Very High Income</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="age_coarse">age_coarse</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-age_coarse">
               <li>Child</li>
               <li>Middle Aged</li>
               <li>Older</li>
               <li>Younger</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="family_stage">family_stage</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-family_stage">
               <li>Family Mix</li>
               <li>Family Unknown</li>
               <li>W/ Kids</li>
               <li>W/O Kids</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="home_scale">home_scale</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-home_scale">
               <li>Low Scale</li>
               <li>Medium Scale</li>
               <li>Upscale</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="education_imputed">education_imputed</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-education_imputed">
               <li>Attended Vocational/Tech</li>
               <li>Completed College</li>
               <li>Completed Graduate School</li>
               <li>Completed High School</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.extra-attri-div').find('.appendeddiv').each(function(i){
        console.log("coming"+i);
        console.log($(".extraattrlebl").data('extraatt'));
        
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beccause each time you are calling `console.log($(".extraattrlebl").data('extraatt'));` jQuery finds the first `extraattrlebl` in the whole document (not just inside the `.appendeddiv` ) and returns  the value of data-extraatt >> `environment`

You need to fetch inside each `.appendeddiv` using the `.find()`

Try this code:

```js
$('.extra-attri-div').find('.appendeddiv').each(function(i){
        console.log("coming"+i);
        console.log($(this).find(".extraattrlebl").data('extraatt'));
        
        // select the list
        let lis =  $(this).find("ul li")
       
        // print each li
        lis.each(function() {
          console.log($(this).text())
        });
        
        console.log("\n\n")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row extra-attri-div">
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="environment">environment</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-environment">
               <li>Suburban</li>
               <li>Urban</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="income_coarse">income_coarse</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-income_coarse">
               <li>Middle Class</li>
               <li>Upper Middle Class</li>
               <li>Very High Income</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="age_coarse">age_coarse</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-age_coarse">
               <li>Child</li>
               <li>Middle Aged</li>
               <li>Older</li>
               <li>Younger</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="family_stage">family_stage</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-family_stage">
               <li>Family Mix</li>
               <li>Family Unknown</li>
               <li>W/ Kids</li>
               <li>W/O Kids</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="home_scale">home_scale</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-home_scale">
               <li>Low Scale</li>
               <li>Medium Scale</li>
               <li>Upscale</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col appendeddiv">
      <div class="label-value">
         <label class="extraattrlebl" data-extraatt="education_imputed">education_imputed</label>
         <div class="value">
            <ul id="li-education_imputed">
               <li>Attended Vocational/Tech</li>
               <li>Completed College</li>
               <li>Completed Graduate School</li>
               <li>Completed High School</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the same way just use `.find('ul li')`  I updated the code.